# If a NATO member annexes territory of a non-NATO state, would its NATO membership be revoked?

Tags: international-relations, nato

Imagine for a moment that Poland annexes Ukraine. For simplicity let's assume that:

1. Poland annexes only those parts of Ukraine which are not under the control of Russia or Russian proxies (i.e. Crimea and Luhansk/Donetsk republics are not annexed), and it does not stake any claims to those territories.
2. The annexation takes place after a referendum in Ukraine took place, in which 60% of population voted for being annexed by Poland, and which was recognised by international community as free and fair.

**Question:** would this new Poland still be a NATO member after the annexation?

(I know this is not even a remotely realistic situation; I bet Ukrainians would vote against any annexation in the traditional sense of the word, i.e. being completely governed from Warsaw. More realistic would be a formation of a new state similar to UK which contains Poland and Ukraine as countries, but in this case I think I know the answer, so I want to strictly stick to this unrealistic scenario.)

Comment: Why would the membership be revoked?

Comment: @phoog Well, imagine for example the following scenario: Lithuania "annexes" Kaliningrad enclave, then Russia attacks Lithuania in response, then Lithuania invokes NATO article 5. Very likely this invocation would be considered by other members "not in the spirit" of the purpose of NATO, wouldn't it? So it's not unreasonable to enquire whether there is a built in mechanism in the NATO treaties against this kind of situations.

Comment: I see.  I suppose that the mechanism would be found in the definitions describing situations where the article could be invoked rather than in a provision for expulsion.  I seriously doubt, however, that the peaceful, democratically supported annexation described in this question would engage any such mechanism.

Comment: You can read the treaty text online and judge for yourself https://www.nato.int/cps/en/natolive/official_texts_17120.htm

Comment: @Stuart F I thought that there might be some other treaties apart from the foundational ones which specify additional rules, requirements etc.

Comment: Indeed, the broader question here is a good one: whether there's a mechanism to prevent NATO members from being involved in a conflict begun by the unilateral aggression of a NATO member and, if there is, what the relevant conditions are.

Comment: @phoog, yes though in the scenario I'm asking about  it's hardly an "aggression". I think if it was aggression then TenthJustice's answer could perhaps apply i.e. the commandment "thou shalt be a good neighbour", but I don't see how this commandment applies in the situation I'm asking about (or say if Norway annexed Finland and Sweden with 90% support of the population of Finland and Sweden).

Comment: You are engaging in a bit of equivocation as to whether you're talking about a hostile annexation or a consensual one. In the question you go out of your way to say it's consensual, but then when asked in the comments why you think it would be a problem, you present a hostile one. Clearly Article V applies only to unprovoked attacks. If NATO had existed prior to WWII, Germany would not have been able to invoke Article V in response to the UK bombing them, because Germany initiated aggression.

Comment: I agree with @Acccumulation's comment. One may add that the question presupposes that the annexing country is doing "something wrong", otherwise there's no reason for their NATO membership to be revoked. Also the term [annexation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annexation) refers to the "forcible acquisition", so it's very likely hostile anyway.

Comment: @Erwan Your comment seems to be contradicitcting the established usages of the word annexation, e.g. here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_annexation

Comment: @ŁukaszGrabowski I don't see any contradiction: Texas was annexed to the US forcibly, against the will of Mexico. Avoiding war with Mexico is even one of the reasons why the US didn't want to do it at first. By contrast the [German reunification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_reunification) is never described as an annexation, since it was not forcible.

Comment: @Erwan I'll give you a pass on Texas, but there are other examples which show that in the common speech the word "annexation" does not necessarily imply use or threat of use of force e.g.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposed_Canadian_annexation_of_the_Turks_and_Caicos_Islands  Also I struggle to see how there could be any problem with understanding what I mean in the question. The purpose of the other example (Lithuania annexing Kaliningrad) has only been to explain why it's not unreasonable to ask if there exist some NATO rules about annexations (or acquisitions, etc.)

Comment: @ŁukaszGrabowski I'm just pointing out that if the question is about a friendly annexation agreed by everyone, then why would NATO want to revoke membership of the country? They didn't do anything wrong. The first time I read the question I interpreted it as about a hostile annexation, since in this case it would make sense that NATO excludes the country.

Comment: @Erwan, this isn't part of this question, but rather of my motivation for this question: at least to me it's clear that if an annexation as described in the question happened, then Russia would attack the new Poland, even if literally 100% of Ukrainians supported the annexation. Furthermore to me it's very likely that other NATO members would  not help after new Poland invoked artice 5. I was curious how other NATO members could justify their reluctance. The easiest way would be if there's explicitly something in the NATO treaties which deals with such a situation.

Comment: If Ukraine or any other country decides to join Poland, Poland itself must agree as well, it can´t be called annexation. Gues OP is refering to s omething like Rech Pospolita? In this case Ukraine would become not only part of NATO, but EU as well.

Comment: You tallking about something like this? https://southfront.org/ukraine-will-grant-poles-a-special-legal-status/?ysclid=l3kpghc21u

Comment: @convert right now it's impossible to know what's the intention of those laws, and indeed if there is a "coordinated intention" at all. The range of plausible interpretations is from "purely symbolic" to "first step on a long road to some sort of a union entity". Note that over the past decades Poland had pretty much a single coherent foreign policy issue - support Belarus and Ukraine to not be absorbed by Russia. That is still, I believe, the policy, but maybe a reevaluation of how to implement it would be welcome in the light of the fact that Belarus is being absorbed by Russia as we speak.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

NATO member West Germany did annex East Germany, and remained NATO member. There were intensive consultations with other NATO members in the lead up to the annexation.

Comment: Technically, the FRG didn't *annex* the GDR, and doing so involved a contract co-signed by three major NATO powers. So it is a bad example.

Comment: According to wikipedia, "The post-1990 united Germany is not a successor state, but an enlarged continuation of the former West Germany.", so certainly this is applicable in the context of my question

Comment: @ŁukaszGrabowski that's true, but according to the [actual treaty](https://treaties.un.org/doc/Publication/UNTS/Volume%201696/volume-1696-I-29226-English.pdf) I'm not sure that interpretation holds up... it refers to a new united Germany consisting of the territory of the Federal Republic and the GDR and the whole of Berlin.

Comment: @CDJB German wikipedia discusses explicitly the two options which were on the table ("Beitritt der DDR zur Bundesrepublik.." and "Fusion von DDR und ...") and explicitly states that "Beitritt" option was chosen, so I think at least from the point of view of West Germany (i.e. of pre-1990 Bundesrepublik Deutschland)  what happened was exactly the same as if say Jamaica was admitted to the US as a 51st state. But I see that indeed this is not directly addressed in the actual treaty you linked (perhaps the treaty happened first, and only afterwards technical choices were made)

Comment: @ŁukaszGrabowski, under the German constitution, the GDR could *declare* their accession to the FRG and they didn't have to ask for permission to do that. (This option has since been removed.) But more importantly, the international framework was negotiated with the three most important NATO members at the table.

Comment: @o.m. I understand there were negotations. I've accepted the answer because to my best knowledge no NATO treaties had to be changed, from which I deduce that there is no mechanism specified on the level of NATO treaties which would outright forbid a member to annex non-member territory. This is what I wanted to know. Tangentially, I agree (of course) with the statement that in any negotiations at least some other NATO members would be reluctant to recognise the new Poland as being able to trigger article 5, and I'm curious what non-treaty-based arguments they'd use, but that's not my question.

Comment: This is an interesting case, but I'm not sure that it satisfies the definition of [annexation in international law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annexation): *the forcible acquisition of one state's territory by another state*. As far as I know the German reunification was not made by force.

Comment: @Erwan The situation that actually happened with the two Germany's matches the hypothetical situation in the question. Also, the wikipedia article you link lists non-forceful examples, such as the annexation of the Republic of Texas by the USA (the violent part was the prior separation of Texas from Mexico).

Comment: @Arno see discussion with OP in the comments of the question itself.

Answer (score 4):

**Possibly**. The text of the actual NATO treaty is [quite short and accessible](https://www.nato.int/cps/en/natolive/official_texts_17120.htm). There is no article requiring the removal of a state that annexes or invades a neighbor. In fact, there's no expulsion language at all. But the [general understanding](https://www.justsecurity.org/66574/can-turkey-be-expelled-from-nato/) when enacted was the lack of an expulsion clause wasn't an issue, as any state that failed to live up to the ideals set up in Article 1 and 2 could be declared in material breach of their treaty obligations:

> Article 1 The Parties undertake, as set forth in the Charter of the
> United Nations, **to settle any international dispute in which they may
> be involved by peaceful means in such a manner that international
> peace and security and justice are not endangered, and to refrain in
> their international relations from the threat or use of force in any
> manner** inconsistent with the purposes of the United Nations.
>
> Article 2 **The Parties will contribute toward the further development
> of peaceful and friendly international relations** by strengthening
> their free institutions, by bringing about a better understanding of
> the principles upon which these institutions are founded, **and by
> promoting conditions of stability and well-being. They will seek to
> eliminate conflict in their international economic policies** and will
> encourage economic collaboration between any or all of them.

After the dissolution of the USSR, NATO also set out a "Membership Action Plan" that prospective members would have to meet in order for their application to NATO to be approved. The five major requirements are:

> --New members must uphold democracy, including tolerating diversity.
>
> --New members must be making progress toward a market economy.
>
> --Their military forces must be under firm civilian control.
>
> --**They must be good neighbors and respect sovereignty outside their borders.**
>
> --They must be working toward compatibility with NATO forces.

Technically speaking, these are only requirements for *entering* NATO, not ongoing membership, and they were only laid out after Poland had already joined. But in combination, there is a strong assumption that NATO members act and look a certain way. Even if Poland's annexation was bloodless and done in a bare democratic fashion, it would pretty clearly be in violation of NATO's general request that members act like good neighbors and promote regional stability.

The question would then become whether other NATO members actually feel obliged to press the issue or look the other way (as they currently do for a lot of Turkey's bad behavior). Unlike the democratic ideals promoted by NATO, the "good neighbors" expectation is also one of practicality. NATO is obligated to come to the defense of Poland if they are attacked, the expectation from other NATO states is that Poland in return should not be out there provoking conflict with its neighbors and forcing them into unnecessary and unjust wars.

The thing to keep in mind here is treaties are only as strong as the will to abide by them. The text of the NATO obligations could be clear cut in Poland's favor, but if the other NATO states *don't want* to come to Poland's aid, the international treaty police are not going to show up and make them. If Poland says "We're in NATO," and every other participating nation says "ah, but we'd prefer if you weren't," practically speaking, Poland is not in NATO any longer and the question if they *legally* are is entirely academic.

Comment: To avoid misunderstanding, could you say explicitly why in the situation I described "it would pretty clearly be in violation of NATO's general request that members act like good neighbors and promote regional stability." ?

Comment: From the perspective of Russia, it would effectively be the same as Ukraine joining NATO. Right now Ukraine and Belarus are buffers between NATO and Russia, the annexation would reduce that buffer to a mere roadbump.

Comment: Tangential comment: it's an interesting point of view. I tend to think that creating a Poland-Ukraine state would be economically extremely beneficial to both nations, if there ever was will on both sides (which there isn't). And this opinion of mine is based purely on considerations of economy, not military alliances. But it seems that you're (not  unreasonably) suggesting that even if there was an overwhelming will to form Poland-Ukraine state, both nations would essentially have to first ask Russia for permission.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no. Turkey has annexed the north part of Cyprus even without any kind of referendum and is still a NATO member.

Comment: I don't think Turkey has annexed any part of Cyprus?

Comment: @ŁukaszGrabowski Oh, if you leave it as *one or both of two present NATO members did bad things in Cyprus and are still members* it answers the question plenty well.  This situation is just not what NATO's scope of concern is - resisting external invasion - , directly.

Answer (score 2):

This would be an unprecedented situation, and taking analogies from history are pointless. NATO members have committed to **consult** on security questions and to **plan** together.

- Either the annexing member **has** consulted and has the consent of the other members. Then it should be equally easy to extend membership to the rump state that is to be protected.
- Or the annexing member **has not** consulted, then that will earn the wrath of the other members. Possibly up to the point where the political guarantees of NATO protection are no longer credible.
- The only scenario where this could be remotely relevant is if a cabal of powerful NATO members wants to sidestep the formal NATO processes, but then they could always unilaterally give guarantees with the same scope as Article 5.

Comment: Perhaps it is not clear to you but the intent of the question was to specifically determine if there's a  mechanism built into any NATO treaties designed specifically to deal with annexation. The statements which you are making, namely that _in absence of such a mechanism_  it would be a question of negotiations between NATO members, is clear. But again, the question was about presence/absence of such a mechanism

Comment: Isn't annexing without consulting the annexed territory [against](https://casebook.icrc.org/glossary/annexation-prohibition) international law?

Comment: @doneal24, the OP assumed just such a consultation for purposes of this question.

Comment: @ŁukaszGrabowski, my answer is that assuming that there must be such a mechanism is a misunderstanding of NATO. NATO was always the **bet** that the US would sacrifice New York to avenge Paris, because they could either fight together with western Europe or a couple of years later alone, without them. Europe never *quite* believed that, hence the UK and French independent nuclear deterrence. The UK hedged against the US nerve failing when push came to shove by buying American missiles, France hedged against the US splitting from Europe by building a tout azimut nuclear deterrent.

Comment: I don't think anyone, certainly not me, is "assuming that there must be such a mechanism", essentially my question is whether there is such a mechanism explicitly specified on the level of signed treaties.

Answer (score 1):

There are the rules and there is reality. There are multiple examples of annexation of territories not leading to problems with NATO. For instance, Turkey has de-facto annexed the north-western part of Syria. Whether it eventually does it formally or not doesn't matter as far as Turkey's NATO membership. Considering that purchasing Russia's S-400 system despite the threat of US sanctions hasn't even raised the question of Turkey's NATO membership, we can see that the bar for expulsion from NATO is extremely high, indeed.